# My logo goes blurry when I try and upload it to instagram

Tags: adobe-photoshop, resize, image-quality, compression

I've made a logo in photoshop, it's high quality. When I then export and try to upload as my instagram profile picture, it becomes blurry. Is anyone able to help.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please do not upload higher resolution images for instagram or google profile, facebook, twitter or any such app where your logo has to be resized.

The best method is, You scale down logo by yourself and upload then. I guess it shouldn't be more than 300x300 in resolution.

What happens actually, the automated resizer in applications, just lower down the scale of image, and pixels are rasterized using anti aliasing.

Just for understanding... 
If required size is 10 X 10 pixels and your image is 1000 x 1000 pixels, it will merge every 100 pixels into 1 pixel. so if your line in larger image was on 50 pixels in X axis, that will be blurred and mixed with surrounding pixels.

So make a small image by yourself in photoshop. And then upload. That will be super sharp.